# Breaking an int into a sum

Tags: python, math

Preamble: I'm aware of the change-making algorithm and this unfortunately doesn't apply here. Accordingly to what I've understood, the change-making algorithm goal is to break the value into the sum of a **minimum** number of terms. This isn't my point, I want to be able to break the value into the sum of **any given** number of terms.

I am having trouble with a problem of mine, and was wondering if you'd have any hints/tips. Basically, I have a variable (an int) that I want to break into an addition of a given number of terms. And, because it was too simple, these terms must be chosen from an array of possible terms. (Let's assume here there's at least one way to do it, verifications would have been done before). Allow me to illustrate:

```
var = 12
nbr_terms = 3
possible_terms = [2, 3, 4, 6]
# Function to create
breaker(var, nbr_terms, possible_terms)
```

The `breaker()` function should return (one of) the decomposition. For example, here it could be `6+3+3` or `4+4+4`.

I have an idea that I think could work, merely it could become extremely resource consuming if the `possible_terms` array was to have a lot of elements. It would be to loop through this array to test every combination possible of the given number of terms, to store every working combination in an other array, and pick one randomly. Besides, as the `nbr_terms` is also a parameter, I wouldn't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do it recursively. The function finds all the possible combinations (`2+4+6` is different from `4+2+6` for this function) and return the list then I pick one of them randomly.

Here's the function:

```
def broker(var, nbr_terms, possible_terms, list_all, nbr, term, current_list):
    if(term == nbr_terms and nbr == var):
        list_all.append(current_list)
    elif(nbr < var and term < nbr_terms):
        for i in possible_terms:
            broker(var, nbr_terms, possible_terms, list_all, nbr+i, term+1, current_list+[i])
```

Allow me to explain the args: `var`, `nbr_terms` and `possible_terms` are the same as in the question, `list_all` is the list of the working combinations and `nbr`, `term` and `current_list` are the recursive args.

I think that's all, thanks to tianlinhe who also responded!

Answer (score 0):

I guess `combinations_with_replacement` from `itertools` is what you need.
So it will yield all the combinations of `possible_terms` without replacement, and you can assign the number of element in each combination (in you case, it is `nbr_terms)`.
The following codes should work:

```
import itertools as it
def breaker(var, nbr_terms, possible_terms):
    results=[]
    for i in it.combinations_with_replacement(possible_terms, nbr_terms):
       # print (i, sum(i))
        if sum(i)==var:
            results.append(i)
    return results
```

I ran it with the numbers you provided:

```
var = 12
nbr_terms = 3
possible_terms = [2, 3, 4, 6]
breaker(var, nbr_terms, possible_terms)
```

It returns a list with all 3 possible combinations that sum up to 12:

```
[(2, 4, 6), (3, 3, 6), (4, 4, 4)]
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! This would work perfectly! Merely, it would imply that the combination is sorted (I would have to randomize it later, which is perfectly feasible but it would be an additional step). Furthermore, this is a function from a library, so I'll check the way it works in order to understand it completely, but for this project I prefer doing things myself if it is possible. Still, thank you for your answer, it'll help me for other projects!

Comment: You're welcome! You can definitely study [itertools] (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) document, where you find the equivalent codes there. If the answer is correct, could you accept it as answer?